# Multiple Markers on google map using Django

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps-markers

I am trying to place multiple markers on google map by passing a coordinate list in Django. But when a page is rendered no marker is there. Can anybody help me in pointing out what is the problem in my code:

Html Code:

```
<script>

        {{ coordinatelist }}

      var map;

      function initMap() {

        // Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

          center: {lat: 40, lng:0},

          zoom:1,
            minZoom:1


        });

      }
        {% for item in coordinatelist %}
            var latlongcoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng({{ item.0 }},{{ item.1 }});
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: he,
            title:"Mymarker"});
            marker1.setMap(map);
        {% endfor %}
```

Generated Javascript:

```
    [[39.095963, -108.193359], [44.150681, -93.251953]]

  var map;

  function initMap() {

    // Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

      center: {lat: 40, lng:0},

      zoom:1,
        minZoom:1


    });

  }

        var he = new google.maps.LatLng(39.095963,-108.193359);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: he,
        title:"Mymarker"});
        marker.setMap(map);

        var he = new google.maps.LatLng(44.150681,-93.251953);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: he,
        title:"Mymarker"});
        marker.setMap(map)
```

Comment: Can you show the generated JavaScript in the HTML source?

Comment: I have added that in the orignal question

Comment: Hi i have resolved it ,it was outside the initmap function